# Passing self to function which is called inside field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

What I am trying to do is to call a function inside field which parameter help:

```
 class RouteLocation(models.Model):
      _name = 'route.location'

      time_change_comment = fields.Char()

      def time_change_comment(self):
          if self.time_change_comment:
             return self.time_change_comment
          else:
             return "Something else"

      time = fields.Datetime(help=time_change_comment(CAN't pass self here))
```

I have tried to do so far is to play a little bit with lambda, but i did't succeed.

Is there anyway to workaround this situation. Thanks for you time :)

Comment: Your time variable is outside the scope of a self instance (indentation matters)

Comment: Also, it's after a return, which makes it dead code if you did intent it there

Comment: So this solution is completely bad. Is there any other way I could pass field value to 'help'?

Comment: Why can't you set it up with `__init__` as previously answered?

Comment: Firstly I don't see the answer, secondly no idea how to do that. Probably I will have to find completely different solution. Anyway thank you friend, have a great day.

Comment: what you trying to achieve,need more description.

Answer (score 0):

first a quick explaination and then what I believe is the solution to your problem.

1. You don't need to pass `self` to a method, it is passed implicitely. But then...
2. You **do need** `self` to call a method (as in `self.method_name()`), you could add `@classmethod` to `time_change_comment` (BTW, can you change the name so it doesn't clash with the property above?) but then you won't have an instance abd you need that to properly access your model data.
3. As far as I can think using lambdas will get you to the same point. How do you capture `self`?

Took a quick look at [models.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/models.py) and [api.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/api.py) and it seems that neither `models.MetaModel` nor `api.Meta` circunvent initialization in `models.BaseModel` so as @criket_007 said, using `__init__` is your best choice

```
  def __init__(self, pool, cr):
      # remember we changer the function time_change_comment's name
      self.time_change_comment.help = self.time_change_comment_fn()
```